# How to change project title in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I want to change project title(demo) in IntelliJ IDEA but I can't find a way to change it, the directory has renamed but the title doesn't change

in `File > Open Recent` show demo name!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change `demo` to your project name in following path: **.idea/.name**.
Then restart the IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it is Gradle or Maven project you should change the name in Gradle or Maven configuration. E.g. in `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'someName'
```

or in Maven root `pom.xml`:

```
...
<artifactId>someName</artifactId>
...
```

If project does not use any build systems rename it in File | Project Structure | Project | **Project name:** field:

[image]

Comment: Which method does not work exactly? What project type do you have?